# Should I be concerned about enabling too many modules at the same time?

Tags: 7

I am using features to manage deployment.  I have a controller feature which lists 8 other features I have created as dependencies.  These features in turn together list over 100 modules as dependencies.  Is it ok to simply turn on the controller module and allow it to automatically enable all the other modules, or does Drupal have trouble doing this?

So far when I enable them all at once it seems fine, but I'm just asking to make sure I don't have problems down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess it depends on max_execution_time in your php.ini settings. And maybe similar setting in your my.cnf file on your server(mysql configuration).